# C program for display assembly in binary files

Tags: c, assembly

i'm trying to display the assembly instructions in a binary files but how can i do?
how can i know if an argument of MOV ( for example ) is a pointer or a number ?
this is for educational purposes, i known that there is GDB and othrer tools.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I would definitely look at some disassembler source code to get a better idea of how this is done. x86 is incredibly complex and there is a lot involved, but it is still possible to do, just be prepared to handle a lot of edge cases.

Comment: the same way the processor can tell...by looking at the opcodes.  I would start with some other instruction set before spending time with x86.  (having the hardware has nothing to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

You mean a [disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler)? then you have many tools to pick from, such as:

- OllyDbg
- IDA
- objdump

If you want to integrate this into an existing program, then you need a disassembly engine, such as [BeaEngine](http://www.beaengine.org/) or diStorm.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i think beaengine is what i'm searching for but how can i use it?  gcc -g -I include -L lib/Linux.gnu.Debug -l BeaEngine_s_d disass_test.c use the compiled library and include beaengine headers but but i still have: undefined reference to `BeaEngineVersion', what i'm missing? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize many of the libraries inside [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) like **BFD** and **opcodes**.

**BFD** *Binary File Descriptor library*, to do low-level manipulation.

**opcodes** library is used to assemble and disassemble machine instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful information from the source to an [emulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4732/2381), which has to perform the same decoding task before performing the simulated instruction.

I highly recommend targeting a small subset first, ideally the bare 8086, and then add extensions in the same sequence they historically happened. This will help you decide what to ignore when looking for more information. So as not get overwhelmed.

For the MOV operation, the operands are specified (in the most general form) by the second byte, the MOD-REG-REG/MEM byte. Operands are almost always registers or memory locations (pointers, possibly constructed on-the-fly using "indexing registers"). Only a few instructions accept a literal operand(a number) and only as the *source*, and they are clearly marked in the table, [1979 8086 Manual](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/data_sheets/Intel_8086_users_manual.htm), on page 180.